# Displaying results of a MySQL temp table using PHP - caching?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I am currently having an issue where MySQL is only displaying 1 of my 3 rows in a dynamic Temporary Table I've created in a PHP page. I can confirm how many rows the TmpTable has via:

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($doResults);
```

(returns 3)

But when I do my `while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($doResults)) { }`, only 1 of the 3 rows are returned/displayed. The one row is returned correctly with all fields requested.

Has anyone had any issues with some sort of Caching, etc ... ?

Comment: Try posting the query itself, and/or a bigger snippet of code. Something containing the query and the fetch loop. Also, take a look at mysqli_fetch_all() if you're running PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array) returns the next record in the result set, only one record. The name of your variable $row**s** suggests that you expect otherwise.

Try something like

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // only for debugging
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // only for debugging

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($doResults);
echo '<pre>debug: $numrows=', $numrows, "</pre>\n";
$dbgcRow = 0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($doResults)) {
  // row counter / number of the current record
  echo '<pre>debug: $dbgcRow=', ++$dbgcRow, "</pre>\n";
  // print the values of the current record
  echo htmlentities(join(',', $row)), "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply ... I ended up figuring out my issue. I had a second while loop inside my while loop that was causing it to exit after displaying 1 row. Changed to for loop and works great now!

Thanks again and God Bless
-L